# Sum data based on dates

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a Google Sheet of data like this:

```
4/1/17 | 5
4/1/17 | 7
4/1/17 | 22
4/2/17 | 5
4/2/17 | 10
4/3/17 | 5
4/3/17 | 23
4/3/17 | 1
4/3/17 | 5
4/3/17 | 17
4/3/17 | 3
```

And I want some sort of formula that I can apply to this range to return this:

```
4/1/17 | 34
4/2/17 | 15
4/3/17 | 54
```

(Obviously any date can have any number of entries and it needs to be expandable so that another date can be added - e.g. 4/4/17 - and the "result range" will automatically populate a new row)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in ColumnsA:B then your first date in say D1 and in E1:

```
=sumif(A:A,D1,B:B)
```

is not fully automatic (you would have to drag D1:E1 down to suit) but should give the desired output. Provided dragged far enough further data added to B:C should update D:E.

Comment: Is there any way to have a formula that is "fully automatic" (such that it finds the unique dates and populates the "D" column for me?)

Comment: Great! It's a shame that the SUMIF rows will just have to "sit there" until that date gets entered, but I guess there isn't a better option? Thanks!

Comment: What other details would you like? I can provide whatever information you need